# Why does this not work (HTML, CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm having trouble with some code not working, and I'm not sure why. (I am a 1st year Computer Science student as don't know much about this)

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Task1.css" title="Normal">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Task1BaW.css" title="Other">         
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/styleswitcher.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>  
 <div id="header">    <!-- header -->
     <button onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('Normal')">Change style to default</button>
     <button onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('Other')">Change style to Easy view</button>                                   
 </div>    <!-- end of header-->
```

Basically I want it to switch to the "Normal" Css when the 1st button is pressed, and switch to the "Other" Css when the 2nd button is pressed.

Thanks.

NB: I've changed the ‘’ to '(thanks for pointing that out, that was a stupid mistake) and not getting any errors that I'm aware of. Still doesn't seem to be working yet. I'm writing this is PSPad, if that helps at all. And trying it in the IE that PSPad opens and Chrome.

Also, changing the CSS should change the background and text size.

styleswitcher.js code:

```
function setActiveStyleSheet(title) {
 var i, a, main;
 for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
  if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title")) {
   a.disabled = true;
   if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
  }
 }
}

function getActiveStyleSheet() {
 var i, a;
 for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
  if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title") && !a.disabled) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
 return null;
}

function getPreferredStyleSheet() {
  var i, a;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
       && a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("alt") == -1
       && a.getAttribute("title")
       ) return a.getAttribute("title");
      }
  return null;
}

 function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

window.onload = function(e) {
  var cookie = readCookie("style");
  var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
  setActiveStyleSheet(title);
}

window.onunload = function(e) {
  var title = getActiveStyleSheet();
  createCookie("style", title, 365);
}

var cookie = readCookie("style");
var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
setActiveStyleSheet(title);
```

If anyone has a simpler way of doing this instead of fixing this, and can explain it to me so I can understand why it works, I'd appreciate it too.

Comment: Why are you using fancy `‘’` use simple `''`

Comment: For future reference: Include whatever error messages you get in your question along with the intended and observed behavior.

Comment: It's also better to use `$("button").click(function(){});`  instead of `onclick=` argument.

Comment: And perhaps even better to do `$("button").on("click",function(){});` except he also does not load jQuery

Comment: Can you please paste the file `scripts/styleswitcher.js`?

Comment: @MattBurland Found an error. Says that the setActiveStyleSheet is not defined.

Comment: @Reeno Pasted the file.

Comment: @user3388773: Where is your javascript in relation to your html?

Comment: @MattBurland The javascript file is in a 'scripts' folder which is in the same folder as the the html.

Comment: @user3388773: That wasn't exactly what I was getting at. Where is the `<script>` tag that loads it relative to your html? Also, are you sure it is actually loading your script?

Comment: @MattBurland Within the <head></head> at the top of the html page. I hope it is loading, but not sure how to check. the code I'm using is: <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/styleswitcher.js"> </script>

Comment: @user3388773: Most browsers have a network tab in their developer console. Turn it on and hit reload on the page. Also you can probably check in the console to see if it has the `styleswitcher.js` file as a source you can look at.

Comment: @MattBurland Bah, I'm an idiot. Seems like it will work perfectly if I remove the first '/' in the  src="/scripts/styleswitcher.js" bit. So works when I use src="scripts/styleswitcher.js". -_-. I'm feeling stupid now, so I'll go crawl in a dark hole somewhere. Thanks you all your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @user3388773: Not to worry. We all have those once in a while.

Answer (score 10):

In javascript, you have to use `'` or `"`.

Your quote `‘` and `’` isn't valid.

Since you did that, even StackOverflow's syntax highlighting failed!!

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem to have corrected the problem, but that was a mistake that I should have seen >.<

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
<div id="header">    <!-- header -->
     <button onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('Normal')">Change style to default</button>
     <button onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('Other')">Change style to Easy view</button>                                   
</div>    <!-- end of header-->
```

Comment: Thanks, though not fixed the code, I appreciate the correction.